# PHP DOMDocument - createDocumentFragment does not work with loadHTML

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, fragment

I have a string that contains HTML and I would like to insert this HTML in a DOMElement.

For that, I did:

```
$abstract = "<p xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">Test string <formula type="inline"><default:math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><default:mi>&pi;</default:mi></default:math></formula></p>"

$dom = new \DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($abstract);     
$frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
```

When var dumping the `$frag->nodeValue`, I am getting null. Any idea?

Comment: Remove \ and `@` from that code and you'll get your answer

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, no, this will not resolve the problem: the \ is for Symfony framework, to be able to find the DomDocument class, the @ is to hide warnings, because I have some non common tags that should be loaded.

Comment: The \ is for the top level php namespace. It is optional if you're are outside a namespace (in the top level namespace). The @ blocks errors, but the Math-ML part is broken anyway.

Comment: What did you *expect* to get? What is the "value" of a childless node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you expect, you creating a new fragment and you add no content. Even if you do it would not work because the document fragment is no node, it is an helper construct to add a XML fragment to a document.

Here is an example:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$body = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('body'));

$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXml('<p>first</p>second');

$body->appendChild($fragment);

echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Output:

```
<body><p>first</p>second</body>
```